# Find missing dates from a range of dates in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `collection` which contains a `serviceDate` field for a particular operation.
I need to find for a given date range is there any `serviceDate` which is missing and if it is found the return list of `serviceDate dates` missing between the range of date in MongoDB.
Sample JSON for my collection is as below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cefdb46bfbe1c0001f38413"),
    "category" : "RENT",
    "serviceDate" : ISODate("2019-06-15T05:30:00.000+05:30")
},


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cefdb46bfbe1c0001f38412"),
    "category" : "RENT",
    "serviceDate" : ISODate("2019-06-14T05:30:00.000+05:30")
},


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cefdb46bfbe1c0001f38411"),
    "category" : "RENT",
    "serviceDate" : ISODate("2019-06-13T05:30:00.000+05:30")
}
```

Example:
**Case 1:**
If a collection has 10 documents and the serciceDate starting from 1-June-2019 to 10-June-2019.
In my Query I am passing 4-June-2019 to 7-June-2019 than result should be null.
**Case 2:**
If a collection has 9 documents and the serciceDate starting from 1-June-2019 to 10-June-2019, but 6-June-2019 is missing.
In my Query I am passing 4-June-2019 to 7-June-2019 than result should be 6-June-2019.
**Case 3:**
If a collection has 9 documents and the serciceDate starting from 1-June-2019 to 10-June-2019, but 6-June-2019, 5-June-2019 is missing.
In my Query I am passing 4-June-2019 to 7-June-2019 than result should be 6-June-2019 and 5-June-2019.

Comment: By range of dates you mean you just specify dates with fixed time part `05:30:00.000+05:30` ?

Comment: @mickl You can ignore the timestamp part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first find all the dates between the date range you pass in the query. Which you have to do with some javascript trick.

```
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = []
  var currentDate = moment(startDate)
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate)
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days')
  }
  return dateArray
}

const dateArray = getDates(startDate, startDate)

//Output will be something like
dateArray = [ "2018-09-01", "2018-09-02", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-04", "2018-09-05" ]
```

Now you you can use aggregation to find the [**`$setDifference`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to get the non-existing `serviceDates`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match': {
    'serviceDate': { '$gte': startDate, '$lte': endDate }   
  }},
  { '$group': {
    '_id': null,
    'dates': { '$push': { '$dateToString': { 'date': '$serviceDate', 'format': '%Y-%m-%d' }}}
  }},
  { '$project': {
    'missingDates': { '$setDifference': [dateArray, '$dates'] }
  }}
])
```